# Nutch - parse custom HTML elements

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I'm trying to crawl and index (with Solr) specific parts of the pages I'm crawling.

So far with all the default Config I'm crawling and indexing the pages I want, but in Solr I only have 2 field, title and content, which contains the text of my pages, but it's not exactly the text that I want.

What I want to achieve is to have new field with the content of a specific div.

`<div class="myDiv"> Content I want to index </div>`

What I found so far is the [Extractor Plugin](https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search) which seems to be what I want.

After following the instructions I'm not able to parse the data since I get the following error and I don't understand what's wrong.

I'm using Nutch 1.15

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/nutch/plugin/PluginClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the slf4j-api used was an old version which didn't match with the one that Nutch uses. At least, that's what I understood.

To solve the issue I simply commented out the library in `/plugins/extractor/plugin.xml`

Remove this line: `<library name="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>`

Comment: Hi. I'm also facing same issue. but commenting out the line ```<library name="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>``` didnt work.  It gives null pointer exception for me.

```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ir.co.bayan.simorq.zal.extractor.nutch.ExtractorIndexingFilter.filter(ExtractorIndexingFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilters.filter(IndexingFilters.java:52)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFiltersChecker.process(IndexingFiltersChecker.java:248)
```